# Gnome-session-fall-back unity not working

Tags: 12.04, unity

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 in my old PC.But when I tried to change unity to gnome-session-fall-back,it is not working.When I login with  gnome-session-fall-back unity I am only getting default Ubuntu unity.I also installed LXDE desktop.But same problem still persist.

Can I install gnome-session-fall-back or LXDE desktop in my PC. If so how can it be done.

suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Might not be selecting the different desktop when logging in, is there an icon or anything to change when putting in your login name?

Comment: I am selecting LXDE session from the log in screen and it's icon also changes.But when logging in I am only getting default Ubuntu unity.Tried other theme packages also but it also giving default unity.

Answer (score 0):

Are the packages installed? They should be in the Software center, or Synaptic, or `aptitiude` or `apt-get`

I think the Gnome one is called `gnome-session-flashback` now, but there should be a `gnome-session-fallback` transitional package available too.

And the LXDE metapackage is just called `lxde`

I *think* they should be available to choose when you log in next. If they're not, then checking what login manager is running & it's settings is next

Comment: The question says he has already done this.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what has been installed, he says he installed "LXDE desktop", but also says *"Can I install gnome-session-fall-back or LXDE desktop in my PC. If so how can it be done."*

Comment: I think [this comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/563557/gnome-session-fall-back-unity-not-working/567070?noredirect=1#comment780910_563557) cleared most of that up

Comment: Can't hurt to start with the basics, especially for a 1 rep asker. Could've extracted a tarball from who knows where after all